# TypeError: string indices must be integers when parsing JSON

Tags: python, json

This code throws a `TypeError: string indices must be integers` when parsing JSON. Why is that?

```
ids=[]
for line in f:   
    k = json.loads(line)
    if "person" in k:
        for id in ids:
            if k["iden"] == id[0]: #Exception raised here
                #Do some processing
            else:
                ids += [(k["iden"], 1)]
```

Comment: Too badly indented code. Please correct it.

Comment: Please also post the full stack trace - it tells us where the error is happening and makes it easier to help you.

Comment: So what is `k` here? Apparently you have a *string* loaded from `line`, not a dictionary.

Comment: Apparently the problem has to do with id[0]. If I fix it to a constant value, no error is raised. id is a tuple (string,integer)

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads(line)` gives you a string (in *your case*), not a dictionary. If you've got a dictionary, you can use `dictionary['whatever']`, but `your_str['other_str']` won't work. Check your json file, it may be containing some unwanted data.

Here's the documentation on `json.loads(s)`:

> Deserialize s (a str or unicode instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object.

In your case, that *Python object* is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: how can it be a string since it is deserialized into an object? What can cause this?

Comment: @user4636692, `'{"a": "hello"}'` will be loaded as dictionary, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess f is your file.readlines(), and you have something like this before:

```
my_json_file = open('/path/to/file.json')
f = my_json_file.readlines()
my_json_file.close()
```

Try, instead of doing readlines(), to pass the file directly to json.load:

```
my_json_file = open('/path/to/file.json')
k = json.loads(my_json_file)
my_json_file.close()
```